# Can I use an IConverter on a ListBoxItem whose parent ListBox.ItemsSource is bound to a list<int>

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I don't know how to bind to an int since it has no properties.

```
<ListBox Name="AgencyTypeListBox"  >
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
  <DataTemplate>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=whatDoIPutHere, Converter={BLL:CodeMarkupExtension}}" />
  </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In my code behind I do this

```
AgencyTypeListBox.ItemsSource = (List<int>) someListofInts;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the ItemsSource is a list of ints, the data context of each item will already be an integer list entry; you don't need to specify any path.

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={BLL:CodeMarkupExtension}}" />
```